# Is there any possible to update transaction using keys of notary

Tags: corda

am trying to deploying the nodes in different machine. its working fine. But i have many doubts. controller, Notary, customer1 and customer2 are in one MachineA and customer3 and customer4 are in MachineB. if i do any transaction between customer3 and customer4 in machineB, it will generate keys in certificates folder for all nodes.I placed my notary in machineA. Is that possible to update some changes using those keys in machineA without the knowledge of nodes in machineB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificates that you are generated on all the nodes when you conduct a transaction between `customer3` and `customer4` are development certificates that are automatically generated to allow nodes to communicate.

In a real deployment, you'd turn off development mode on each node using a `devMode=false` flag in each node's `node.conf` file. See https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html.

You'd then have to provision each node will proper certificates by following the instructions here: https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html. If you do not provide the proper certificates, your nodes will fail to start with an error like the following:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Identity certificate not found.
>   Please either copy your existing identity key and certificate from
>   another node, or if you don't have one yet, fill out the config file
>   and run corda.jar --initial-registration. Read more at:
>   https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html     at
>   net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.validateKeystore(AbstractNode.kt:460)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:179)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.internal.Node.start(Node.kt:312)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.startNode(NodeStartup.kt:95)
>   ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]     at
>   net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.run(NodeStartup.kt:74)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]  at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:11)
>   [corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]

Comment: how to create certificates? like keypair etc...in which format?

Comment: when i give devMode as false, welcome window of node contains db connection url, ip address, rpc port closed automatically , only window which contains webserver got started and logs are presist. for example, i have three nodes with one controller(devmode=true), when i hit runnodes.bat it would generate 6 windows two for each node , finally one more for controller. if i give false, it would generate 3 windows one for each node. what ll happen if i give devMode=false?

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding. `devMode=false` will mean your nodes won't start properly because they haven't got certs. `devMode=true` (the default) means that your nodes will auto-generate test development certificates and your nodes will start correctly.

Comment: after build , i couldn't find certificate folder in nodes folder then how can i add own CA?? is that i have to create new folder as certificate?